# What is the svn command to commit files of specific revision number only?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am having a repository that contains files of different revision numbers.I want my programmer to provide me the revision number only, so that particular revision numbered files get committed only

Comment: I suspect you are misunderstanding how SVN works or at least using the wrong words. Can you explain further what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes ,lemme explain.I have repository called 'brunch'  where the developers commit files.On the other hand i have another repository called 'trunk' where i commit files to make them live.Now the developers do the work at their own ease and comfort.What i want is the developer who is committing in 'brunch' shud only tell me the particular version no of file committed in branch so that i can make live the changes related to that very particular version number only at a time , not the one which is latest or current.

Comment: I would say the other answer is about right if they're different branches in the same repository (although the -c flag is handy.) I'm not sure if you can merge between different repositories so in that case you would have to export into s working copy of trunk then commit that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're actually looking to merge committed changes from a particular revision into another branch.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html

Here's an example that merges the changes between revisions 30 and 31 to one particular file:

```
svn merge -r 30:31 thhgttg.txt
```

In TortoiseSVN you can to use TortoiseSVN > Merge > Range of revisions.